# Should I use Marlowe or Plutus to create my native token?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, nft, haskell, marlowe

Should I use Marlowe or Plutus to create my token?
I also want to create a TCG in which my token will have an utility.
Where should i start? (tutorial, how-to, examples ...).

Answer (score 1):

Both, `Plutus` and `Marlowe` are smart contract languages. Plutus is a library built on top of Haskell, while Marlowe is based on Plutus. Marlowe should be used by business engineers or financial experts rather than developers. Marlowe is like a financial constructor with a browser-based Contract Editor and simulator. The answer is obvious – ***for trading card game (TCG) development use Plutus***.

Non-fungible token (NFT) in Cardano, however, doesn't require to create smart contact. It's minted as its native asset.